# is using signed_request on cookie for Facebook server side authentication secure?

Tags: security, cookies, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication

Yet another Facebook login question.

I am building a one page site that uses Facebook javascript authentication and login. I do not want any page reloads and want to users to login to Facebook at any time. Login to facebook will change my local views (using backbone.js) but shouldn't refresh the page. Although page is not refreshed I want to have server side (threw REST api) to "know" the uid of the user

I have used Server-side authentication before but wish to work only with client side authentication. (for various reasons)

Basically I follow http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/ but my server is node.js

This is how I see the flow: (with restful API)

```
  1. User enter site
  2. FB JS SDK login/authenticate user
     a. FB SDK has obtained access_token (valid for an hour)
     b. signed request is saved in cookie data (fbsr_<app id>) 
  3. Browser issue any REST API call to Server 
     a. server looks into cookie to identify uid
         Parse the signed_request
         Validates sigend_request with application secret
         identify uid from parsed signed_request
     b. if needed to store long live access token 
         Server exchange code for tokenA
         Server exchange tokenA for longed lived access token (valid for 2 month - fb_exchange_token)
```

Questions:

1. why shouldn't I move the access token from client to server instead of signed_request?
2. is this flow secure?
3. is it good practice?

Thanks